# PHPSESSID in Camelcase? nginx proxy_pass cookies

Tags: php, nginx

I configure nginx proxy for vendor's PHP app. This app expects `PHPSESSID` in uppercase, but Nginx sets it CamelCase, like this:

```
Phpsessid: bo250...f6lbu0
```

My `nginx.conf`:

```
location / {
  # ...
  proxy_set_header 'PHPSESSID' $phpsessid;
  proxy_pass ..
}
```

Yes, I know that [due to RFC-9110 "Field names are case-insensitive.."](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#fields.names), but my vendor dev may not, or older versions of PHP, or et cetĕra..

Is it easy enough to fix this on the server side (in the PHP app)? ("X-Powered-By PHP/5.6.40")

I'm not a php-dev. I want to understand whether it makes sense to request a fix from the vendor.

Comment: If you still got a PHP application running on 5.6, you got bigger problems than this ...

Comment: The first thing you have to do is an urgent PHP upgrade! For serious security concerns

Comment: The `PHPSESSID` is the cookie name not the header name. Cookie names **are** case sensitive so it looks like there's either a misunderstanding or your vendor is doing something extremely odd

Comment: Full picture: `Cookie: foo=bar; PHPSESSID=n9lHvd42zMwIe8kX8Z6CqLvxQ2sDhxRiFLWhoWuz; some-other-cookie=example`

Answer (score 0):

ah, correct syntax is

```
proxy_set_header Cookie "PHPSESSID=$phpsessid; path=/"
```

as rightly noted @Álvaro-gonzález and @apokryfos